# How to print a short type in NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

print the string is using [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"String"];

if I want to print integer, I just use %i, what should I do to print a short type? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [%hi specifier](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good list with many types:
[CocoaDev NSLog](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog)